# How to refine edge when to replace color?

Tags: colors, adobe-photoshop

The original image is as below:

[image]

I want to change the background color into blue.
Operation is ps : image-adjustment-replace color (0000ff)
[image]

The hair's edge color is filled with a little red color,how to refine the edge color now?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer here because the actual **light in the original photo has picked up some of the red** colour of the background and is reflecting off their white shirts. That is, the shirt has actually been coloured red around the edges.

The most realistic result will be to change the colour of this reflected light to blue. Alternatively you could remove its colouring entirely (you're lucky: this would work as we have black/white objects).

One approach would be to:

1. Isolate the people as a separate layer (e.g. Magic Wand on the blue, Invert Select, Cut to new layer)
2. Add a Hue/Saturation adjustment layer on top, set it to clip just to the people layer
3. Use the Brush tool with soft feathering, and paint a mask for this layer which covers just the edges of their shirts/hair
4. Adjust the hue in the adjustment layer until it is blue
5. Reduce the saturation until the effect is subtle (or all the way)

Comment: P.S. You might want to mask out their lips from your original operation, as well, to stop the lips turning blue!